# DateTime elapsed in c#?

Tags: c#, datetime, elapsed

so I'm trying to display messages in a readOnly textbox, with the elapsed time and date, although I'm having some problems. It's displaying that the message was sent 325 days ago, when really it should be 1 min ago. Could someone please help to tell me what I've done wrong?

```
string[] date;
string[] messageArray = 
    File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("~") + "/App_Data/messages.txt");

for (int i = 0; i < messageArray.Length; i++)
{
        date = messageArray[i].Split(' ');
        DateTime date1 = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime date2 = Convert.ToDateTime(messageArray[0]);
        TimeSpan timeDifference = date1.Subtract(date2);
        string formattedTime = "Sent " + timeDifference.Days + " days, " + 
         timeDifference.Hours + " hour/s," + 
         " and " + timeDifference.Minutes + " mins ago";

        File.AppendAllText(Server.MapPath("~") + 
              "/App_Data/messages.txt", "\n" + formattedTime + "\n");
        File.AppendAllText(Server.MapPath("~") + 
              "/App_Data/messages.txt", sendMessageTextBox.Text + 
              System.Environment.NewLine);

}
```

Comment: Please show value of `messageArray[0]`. (You don't really need the rest of the sample...)

Comment: Side note: to format value there is `String.Format` which looks better than sequence of `+`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Running the below

```
        DateTime date2 = DateTime.Now;
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        DateTime date1 = DateTime.Now;

        TimeSpan timeDifference = date1.Subtract(date2);
        Console.WriteLine(timeDifference.Seconds);
```

Show output of `1`

Print the value in `messageArray[0]` to see if it contain what you think it contains

Comment: To express the net elapsed time in seconds, use timeDifference.TotalSeconds (total time expressed in seconds), rather than timeDifference.Seconds (which is the seconds component of the total time).